# Control image upload size in textarea of HTML Form

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using the following WIZWIG editor "http://js.nicedit.com/nicEdit-latest.js" posting into the below HTML form.  I want to control the size of images that are uploaded.  Image size should be something like 200px height, 300px width.  I've tried CSS, HTML & JavaScript to no avail. Can't figure this out...

```
<style>
.nicEdit-main{
background-color: white;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://js.nicedit.com/nicEdit-  latest.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
bkLib.onDomLoaded(function() { nicEditors.allTextAreas({buttonList : ['bold','italic','underline','strikeThrough','html','forecolor','link','upload','unlink','removeformat']}) });
</script>

<form name="comments" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"method="post" onsubmit="return checkForm();">
<?php if ($isGuest) { ?>
Comment:<br><br>
<div style="background: #fff;">
<textarea style="width: 100%;" name="comment" cols="111px" rows="4">disabled for guest account</textarea>
</div>
<input type="submit" name="action" disabled value="Add Comment" />
<?php } else { ?>
Comment:<br><br>
<div style="background: #fff;">
<textarea style="width: 100%;" name="comment" cols="111px" rows="4"></textarea>
</div>
<input type="submit" name="action" value="Add Comment" />  
<?php //header("Location: test.php"); 
} ?>
</form>
```

Comment: Just add the css style `div img{ width: 300px; height: 200px;}`. [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qcy2u67o/)

Comment: Yes that works, the only problem is it styles all images on the page.  I only want to control the images that are being posted in the textarea.

Comment: Is your question about the displayed sizes only or are you more concerned about the file size on your server?

Comment: In that case just use css to target images inside the area. Use this css style `.nicEdit-main img{width: 300px; height: 200px }`.

Comment: Wow almost there..  When I upload images into WIZWIG all looks fine(Thanks PlainDrome555).  But when I click the "Add Comment" button the images appear back to there normal size. :-(  Is there a way I can control image size when there passes to the form section?

Answer (score 0):

Although this was not possible few years ago(you had to send the file to the server side to be able to process file information) now it is do possible with the FileReader() object and pure JS.

You use the `.files[0]` to get the file then create a temporary img object on the DOM(to be able to do the process) and then assign the file to that DOM object(with the help of `FileReader()`)and then you just compare the file width or height. This is an example how you can do it:

```js
imgfile.onchange = function(e) { 
  
      var oFile = document.getElementById("imgfile").files[0]; //Get the selected file by the user
  var img = document.getElementById("imgdom"); //get the reserve image element on the dom to be able do all our processing with this object type
  document.getElementById("imgdom").style.display = "none";//This is optional if you want to show or not the image to the user
  var reader = new FileReader(); //This is the magic object that allows you to process a file on the client side
  reader.onload = function (e) {
    console.log(e.total); // file size 
    img.src =  e.target.result; // putting file in dom without server upload.
    alert(img.width);
    
    //Do what ever condition you want here
    //if img.width > 200 do this, else do that
    
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(oFile );
    
      //return false;
 };
```

```html
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return false;">
<input type="file" name="imgfile" id="imgfile">
</form>
<div>
<img id="imgdom" src="" />
```

Comment: Except you still need to do it server side too as you can never trust client side validation.

Comment: You absolutely don't need a FileReader for this : you can get the file size directly with `input.files[0].size`, and you can get the image dimensions with `img.src=URL.createObjectURL(input.files[0]);`

Comment: @dman2306 if you've got some example of how one can modify a `File` property, I'm curious.

Comment: @Kaiido they can prevent your entire validation function from running. It has nothing to do with modifying a file property. They can modify ALL of the JS. Just press F12 in the browser and you can change anything you want.

Comment: I don't have an F12 on my keyboard, and it won't do anything on my browser, but even if you're right that we shouldn't trust users, I don't think it's related with the actual issue, which seems to be more about displaying sizes and not file sizes.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been resolved with the following CSS Code:

```
.nicEdit-main img {
width: 350px; 
}

img[src*="http://somedomain.com"] {
width: 350px;
}
```

Thanks to all who commented...